# Trouble to publish action

Tags: javascript, authentication, facebook-opengraph

I have two actions that have been approved by Facebook but the action does not work for users, here's the error:

> Error occured Type: OAuthException Message: (#100) The Action Type video:Watch is not approved, so app XXXXXXX can only publish to
>   administrators, developers, and testers of the app. User XXXXXXXX is
>   not one of those roles.

in the settings of the auth dialog I get this error:

> Please note that the 'publish_actions' permission will only be visible
>   to the developers and testers of your app, until your actions are
>   approved. En savoir plus

My two actions are approved.

Only administrators or testers are able to post an action, do you know why?

Thanks you so much for help :)

(Sorry for my poor english, I'm french).

Regards.

Comment: Are you SURE the video watch action is approved for your app? that message seems clear that it is not

Comment: Hello, tes I'm sure: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/710/capturedcran20120321141.png/

Comment: Is that the global action or a custom action specific to your app? Does the sample code from the 'get code' link match what you're trying to do (namespace, etc?)

Comment: Hello, it's a built in action no a custom action. For publish action I used this code: FB.api('/me/video.watches' + 
   '?video='+postPermalink+'&access_token='+access_token,'post',
   function(response) {...

Answer (score 0):

Please subscribe to the following bug and add a repo to catch the attention of the Facebook QA:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/409725722387680

I think it's a bug currently. We can post our actions without any problems from Europe, Asia and the East Coast of US. Though we have the same problem you mentioned if we try to post from the West Coast of the US. We use JS SDK to post, so that's why the Geo Location matters.

Comment: Thanks, I hope they will fix this soon.